# how to auto login the page while not logout the page using php session

Tags: php, session, cookies

The page has to login automatically while not logout the page in php session.

Here using remember me check box when check the box it save the password and login. When I closed without logout and again login the login page is displaying.

Here is the sessionpage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['fname']) && ($_POST['lname'])) {
$_SESSION['fname']=$_POST['fname'];
$_SESSION['lname']=$_POST['lname'];
header('Location: sessionpage1.php');
} 
else{
echo " ";
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($formData['remember_me'])){ 
$twoDays = 60 * 60 * 24 * 2 + time();
setcookie('username', $formData['username'], $twoDays);
    setcookie('password', $formData['password'], $twoDays);
} else { 
    $twoDaysBack = time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 2;
    setcookie('username', '', $twoDaysBack);
    setcookie('password', '', $twoDaysBack);
 }
 }
 ?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name='fname'>
<input type="text" name='lname'>
<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me" value="1" />      <label for="remember_me"> Remember Me </label>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the sessionpage2.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
?>
<?php 
echo "first name".$_SESSION['fname'].  "<br/>";
echo "last name".$_SESSION['lname'] . "<br/>";
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="return">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
session_unset(); 
header('Location: sessionpage.php.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the expected and actual behaviour? Do you get any error messages? And please: use punctuation. No one can understand what you mean.

Comment: there is no error .but when is close the browser withod logout the page what to stay on the same page when again to to the login page

Comment: again, almost no punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['fname']) && ($_SESSION['lname'])) {
  header("Location: your login page.php");
}
```